# Problem with understanding proof of lemma 6.7 in Manin.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In the proof of lemma 6.7 of 'A Course in Mathematical Logic', in page $63$ Manin writes,

" We consider the set $S$ of formulas $P(x)$ containing one free variable $x$ and such that $\neg\forall xP(x)\in \mathscr{E}\ \cup \text{Ax}L'$. For each $P(x)$ in $S$ we choose a new constant $c_P$ subject to the following restriction: each $c_P$ can be assigned a natural number, its $rank$, in such a way that if a constant of rank $n$ occurs in $P(x)$ then $c_P$ has rank $>n$. This can be done since card($S)\leq$ card(alphabet of $L')+\aleph_0=$ card(alphabet of $L)+\aleph_0$"

I am unable to see how the assignment of $c_P$ is justified.

Comment: He simply have added "enough" new constants; see the assumptions of the Lemma.

Comment: But how is the ranking justified?

Comment: Also I don't see how a formula of the form $\neg\forall xP(x)$ can belong to $\text{Ax}L'$ as it can neither be a quantifier axiom, nor a tautology.

Comment: He is considering If a set of formulas $\mathscr{E}$ that is *consistent* and contains AxL. Then "We consider the set $S$ of formulas $P(x)$ containing one free variable $x$ and such that $¬∀x P(x) ∈ \mathscr{E} \cup Ax L'$. For each $P(x)$ in $S$ we choose..." He does **not** says that $¬∀x P(x)$ is a logical axiom.

Comment: As $\neg\forall xP(x)$ can not be a logical axiom thus $\neg\forall xP(x)\in\mathscr{E}\cup\text{Ax}L'$ implies that $\neg\forall xP(x)\in\mathscr{E}$. Then for all such $P(x)$ if we choose a constant $c_P$ from the new set of constants then the occurrence of another $c_{P'}$ in $P(x)$ is not possible. Then why is the ranking done?